# What's the state of the art gem/plugin for tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm redesigning my site currently and replacing all the old plugins. For tags I use [acts_as_taggable_on_steroids](https://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids) and I'm wondering if there are any newer/better gems for Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the similarly named [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) instead.  Better support, and the code originated from that gem you mentioned.

It's pretty good and feature rich AND easy enough to use.